# Solving for unknown, trouble with $\ln$ and $\exp$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Having some trouble understanding $\ln$ and $\exp$ rules and what to do in this situation. Perhaps it has just been a very long day...

$$\hat{Y} = \exp \left[\left(\hat{\beta_0} + \sum_i \hat{\beta_i}{x_i}\right)\space A' \right] $$

Solving for $A'$.

Comment: Are $\hat{Y}$ and $A'$ matrices or real numbers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\ln$ and $\exp$ are inverse of each others. So if
$$ y = \exp(x) $$
this means
$$ \ln(y) = \color{red}{\ln(\exp}(x)) = x. $$
In your case take $\ln$ of both sides. Can you take it from here?